# What is the difference between dedicated server,vpn server and webserver?

Tags: web, hosting

I am confussed about 3 server so you guys can help me?A web hosting service is a type of Internet hosting service that allows individuals and organizations to make their website accessible via the World Wide Web is it right?

Answer (score 0):

A webhosting allows you to store the files of your website online.
A domain allows users to request those files and view them on there browsers.

Getting a complete website pakkage should include both of them.

A vpn is a virtual private server. Also used for websites but in this case you need to configure your webhosting and domain al by your self (not recommanded)

A dedicated server is used to host gamerooms etc.